# How to get webflux webClient metrics from custom Webclient Builder

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, metrics, spring-boot-actuator, spring-webclient

I have created a custom Webclient Builder instead of injecting the default builder.

```
@Configuration
public class WebClientConfig() {

   @Bean(name = "myWebClientBuilder")
   public Webclient.Builder customBuilder() {
      return WebClient.builder();
   }
}
```

I have multiple services where I use this bean `myWebClientBuulder` and do further customization with chain of `ExchangeFilterFunction`.

This might not be the recommended way of using the `WebClient` but I would like to get some insight if there is a way to get the downstream call metrics from the `Webclient` based on this configuration.

Actuator Endpoint: `actuator/metrics/http.client.requests`

Answer (score 1):

Spring Boot auto-configured `WebClient.Builder` is way powerful than customized version.

I tried to configure the custom builder in `WebClientConfig()` but it started to structure just like a copy version of `WebClientAutoConfiguration`. I ended up going with the spring boot autoconfigured `WebClient.Builder` bean.

If it helps, you can study how `WebClientAutoConfiguration` tries to configure webClient customizers. For metrics, it would be `MetricsWebClientCustomizer`.